# KeyChain/KeyStore Backup

Tags: sync, backup, google-backup, backup-manager

Is it possible to backup (local or Cloud) the keys from the keychain/keystore?

I know the KeyChain is a system daemon which provides secure key storage. The keyStore will provide app-specific key storage, but where are the keys located and is it possible to backup the credentials of (all) apps?

Answer (score 1):

The keys are located in the Android System and [stay there indefinitely](https://support.google.com/playedition/answer/2819582?hl=en).

You need to get a new phone, recreate all your keys, revoke all the old ones and reinstall. If you don't know what reinstall means (including but not limited to what to reinstall) get a new phone, recreate all your keys, revoke the old ones and reinstall again.

Google, Carriers and Phone Manufacturers rely on your full cooperation on this matter.